# Keyboard shortcut for Search field in Access (2013) Datasheet view

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

It seems to be a very simple question but I tried it to find an answer in many different sources (including Microsoft web pages) to no effect.

Is there a **keyboard shortcut** to go directly (get focus) into the `Search` box in the *Record Navigation bar*?

[image: Record Navigation bar]

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but Ctrl-F will bring up a dialog where you can type your search criteria. Default is it finds exact match in any field.  You can change the *Match* combo to *Any Part of Field* to find partial matches.  And the dialog is not modal, so you can tinker with the records while it's still open and enter new search criteria without having to close/reopen.
[Find Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK6BW.jpg)

Comment: Thank for your effort but it is out my interest as it is all what I already knew.